# How can I put a flexbox in another?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm learning HTML5/CSS3 for a week and now I'm working on flexbox. I just have a problem, I would like using them make a block "block" which contains two boxes in vertical way and another block "block2" which contains two boxes in horizontal way.

So I would like block and block2 which are in bblock to be next to each other in horizontal way and both sections of block in vertical and both sections of block2 in horizontal way.

But it doesn't works.

What should I do ? Thank you in advance !

```css
.bblock {
  border: 2px solid #444;
  display: flex;
}
.block {
  border: 2px solid #444;
  max-width: 542px;
  /*margin: 0 auto;*/
}
.section:nth-child(1) background-color:orange;
 width:500px;
 max-height:250px;
 border:1px solid black;
 text-align:justify;
 padding-top:0px;
 padding-right:20px;
 padding-left:20px;
 padding-bottom:0px;
 border-radius:10px;

}
.section:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 500px;
  max-height: 170px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: justify;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.block2 {
  border: 2px solid #444;
  max-width: 542px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  /*margin: 0 auto;*/
}
.section2:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 500px;
  max-height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: justify;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.section2:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 500px;
  max-height: 170px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: justify;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="bblock">

  <div class="block">
    <div class="section">
    </div>

    <div class="section">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="block2">
    <div class="section2">
    </div>

    <div class="section2">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's your HTML structure:

```
<div id="bblock">
    <div class="block">
        <div class="section"></div>
        <div class="section"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="block2">
         <div class="section2"></div>
         <div class="section2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want `.block` and `.block2` aligned horizontally, make the parent (`.bblock`) a flex container:

```css
#bblock {
  display: flex;
  /* flex-direction: row;  (this is the default value; it can be omitted) */
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}
.block {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: orangered;
}
.block2 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div id="bblock">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="section"></div>
    <div class="section"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block2">
    <div class="section2"></div>
    <div class="section2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want `.block` and `.block2` aligned vertically, make the parent a flex container with `flex-direction: column`:

```css
#bblock {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}
.block {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: orangered;
}
.block2 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div id="bblock">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="section"></div>
    <div class="section"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block2">
    <div class="section2"></div>
    <div class="section2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

OR, keep the parent `flex-direction: row` and add `flex-wrap: wrap`.Then, make each flex item take 100% of the width, which forces only one item per row.

```css
#bblock {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}
.block {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  background-color: orangered;
}
.block2 {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div id="bblock">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="section"></div>
    <div class="section"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block2">
    <div class="section2"></div>
    <div class="section2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want the children of `.block` stacked vertically and the children of `.block2` lined up horizontally, used nested flex containers and adjust `flex-direction` as needed.

```css
#bblock {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}
.block {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: orangered;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.block > div {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}
.block2 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: flex;
}
.block2 > div {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="bblock">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="section">block section 1</div>
    <div class="section">block section 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="block2">
    <div class="section2">block2 section 1</div>
    <div class="section2">block2 section 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```